# How close is Jmeter average response time to real world average response time for a page

Tags: jmeter

I am running a simple Jmeter test with 10 users and ramp up time of 30 seconds - which means 1 user on a page every 3 seconds. I get an average response time of ~8 seconds per page whereas in real time, how much ever I try, the page loads within 2 seconds. I don't how I should use Jmeter results for measurement. Any help here highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given correct JMeter configuration results are pretty much close to the real user experience.

In order to make your test more realistic consider the following:

1. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to enable cookies support and deal with cookie-based authentication
2. Add [HTTP Header Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) - it might be the case when server is capable of sending compressed data and i.e. browser sends the relevant header, and JMeter doesn't resulting in more data to transfer -> longer response time
3. Real browsers download embedded resources like scripts, styles and images. But real browsers do it **only once**, on subsequent requests resources are being returned from cache. JMeter re-downloads the resources each time. In order to simulate browser's behavior you need to add [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager)
4. "10  users and 30 seconds ramp-up" doesn't necessarily mean "1 user each 3 seconds". In order to ensure that JMeter produces desired hits/s rate add [Constant Throughput Timer](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) to your test plan and set desired throughput there.